# C# .NET How to convert StringBuilder to Byte array without using StringBuilder.ToString()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stringbuilder

When using StringBuilder.ToString(),I'm getting an OutOfMemory exception.
Because my string needs a lot of space.
That is why i need a way (by streaming maybe) to make it work.

This is my code:

```
public static byte[] StringBuilderToByteArray(StringBuilder sb)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] byteArrToReturn = new byte[sb.Length];
    int CHUNK_STRING_LENGTH = 30000;
    byte[] byteArr; 
    int j=0;
    while (sb.Length > CHUNK_STRING_LENGTH)
    {
        byteArr = encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString(0, CHUNK_STRING_LENGTH));
        sb.Remove(0, CHUNK_STRING_LENGTH);
        for(int i=0; i< CHUNK_STRING_LENGTH; i++, j++){
            byteArrToReturn[j] = byteArr[i];
        }
    }
    byteArr = encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++, j++)
    {
        byteArrToReturn[j] = byteArr[i];
    }
    return byteArrToReturn;
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? (streamer?)
Please give answers with code examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CopyTo` method of `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder src = new StringBuilder("Hello!");

char[] dest = new char[src.Length]; 
src.CopyTo(0, dest, 0, src.Length);

Console.WriteLine(dest); //prints Hello!
```

Comment: You are using a char array, not a byte array.